# Comparison method violates its general contract while sorting

Tags: java, sorting

Yeah, I know there are a lot of questions with the same issue but I really can't seem to find what's wrong with my comparator.

So, here it is:

```
evaluateComparator = (m1, m2) -> {
    Color color = m1.getColor(); // m1 and m2 will have the same one
    double m1Value, m2Value;
    if (sortingCache.containsKey(m1)) {
        m1Value = sortingCache.get(m1);
    } else {
        // The value has not been computed before so it's not in the cache and I need to compute it now     
        someClass.doSomething(m1);
        m1Value = someClass.getValue();
        someClass.undoSomething(m1);
        sortingCache.put(m1, m1Value);
    }
    if (sortingCache.containsKey(m2)) {
        m2Value = sortingCache.get(m2);
    } else {
        // The value has not been computed before so it's not in the cache and I need to compute it now     
        someClass.doSomething(m2);
        m2Value = someClass.getValue();
        someClass.undoSomething(m2);
        sortingCache.put(m2, m2Value);
    }
    // Since I'm comparing two doubles I can use the Double's comparator
    return Double.compare(m1Value, m2Value);
};
```

The code is quite simple: I need to sort some objects based on how they would change my main structure, and I want the highest values first.

Since computing the impact of the `m1` or `m2` objects may take some time, I just cache values in order to reuse them so, before sorting, I check if I have a cached value or if I need to compute it.

Once I computed the result of applying `m1` or `m2` to my structure, I revert the changes back.

You can see this like some kind of evaluation sorting taken from the AI's world: 
I want to sort the moves based on the board score that I'd have applying them.

Do you have any idea on this?

EDIT:
Since something strange involving hashing and caching may be involved, I removed all the references to the cache but I still have the issue.

```
evaluateComparator = (m1, m2) -> {
    double m1Value, m2Value;

    someClass.doSomething(m1);
    m1Value = someClass.getValue();
    someClass.undoSomething(m1);

    someClass.doSomething(m2);
    m2Value = someClass.getValue();
    someClass.undoSomething(m2);

    return Double.compare(m1Value, m2Value);
};
```

Comment: A side note, you could have implemented this with half the code if you used the `Comparator.comparingDouble()` combinator.

Comment: Never used it, can you please explain how?

Comment: You just provide the function which extracts the value from one Move object. The combinator returns the full two-argument comparison function (or, technically, the implementation of the Comparator functional interface).

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't exactly count as simple code for a comparator implementation.  A lot of things could go wrong there and the critical code (`doSomething` and `undoSomething`) isn't shown. From the looks of it, `m1` and `m2` are mutable objects and if they change such that they are not equal to themselves from an earlier time, the sorting algorithm breaks. I see this as the most likely explanation of your error.

Another approach to fix your problem, and which I would recommend anyway, is rethinking your approach. Since any sorting algorithm must touch each value at least once, your lazy initialization scheme brings nothing but an overhead in complexity. Instead prepare a plain *list* of moves with their values baked in (you'll need an object representing both the move and its evaluation) and merely sort this list of *immutable* objects using their natural order (a trivial implementation of `compareTo` will do it). At that point your bug will be left with very little place to hide and could possibly disappear before you're done.

Comment: _`m1` and `m2` are mutable objects and if they change such that they are not equal to themselves from an earlier time, the sorting algorithm breaks_ can you please explain this? Do the objects need to stay the same during the sorting process even if their changes do not count for the `getValue` method?

Comment: Their `equals` method is the key (therefore `hashCode` as well, hoping that it's already implemented properly). That's what is used to look up in the cache. So if that changes, each time you ask the map for another key, which it doesn't have. If at that point `getValue` returns something else, the sorting order has changed. Note that there must be *something* which changes the comparsion order because that's (AFAIK) the only way to get the exception.

Comment: Both `equals` and `hashCode` are not using anything that's changed in the `doSomething` method, that's why the situation is quite weird :\

Comment: I've edited the question because I still have the issue even after removing any reference to the cache

Comment: You should also remove value computation from the comparator method.

Comment: Do you suggest to calculate this values before starting the sorting process?

Comment: Exactly, that's what the second paragraph of my answer is devoted to.